# Использование html элементов через bs4

Tags: python-3.x

> Можно ли юзать(нажимать) кнопки на сайте через bs4?
>   Можно ли юзать через этот модуль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bs4 предназначен для синтаксического анализа. Для нажатия кнопок на сайте используйте Selenium webdriver